# Mount-DiskImage fails on Windows 10 host running within vmware

Tags: powershell, vmware, windows-10

I'm trying to mount ISO file through powershell. I'm trying to do that on Windows10 virtual machine running in VMWare Fusion. Same image mounts fine when double-clicked in explorer on the same vm.
I'm using Mount-DiskImage cmdlet like

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "[Path]" -Verbose
```

Error that I'm getting

```
Mount-DiskImage : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:1 char:1
+ Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\vs2013.4_ult_enu.iso" -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_DiskImage:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mount-DiskImage], C
   imException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Mount-DiskImage
```

I've also tried to get more detailed error as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/424794/fail-to-mount-image-files-in-windows-server-2012). Result:

```
writeErrorStream      : True
PSMessageDetails      :
OriginInfo            :
Exception             : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException: The parameter is incorrect.
TargetObject          : MSFT_DiskImage
CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_DiskImage:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mount-DiskImage],
                        CimException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Mount-DiskImage
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      :
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build 10074 or early build's Mount-DiskImage has buggy.
Build 10122 had fix it.

Comment: I had the same question and it answered it for me as its the reason Mount-DiskImage is failing on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the parent folder didn't have SYSTEM with full permission. I added SYSTEM to both, the empty folder and the folder above and it worked. For debugging, just try a top level folder... If that works, work your way down.